# How do I calculate residue and holomorphic range?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Calculate residue and holomorphic range of this function. $f(z)=\frac{z-i}{(z^2+1)^3}$

My idea and problem:

Singularities: $z_0=i,-i$

$Res(f,i)=\lim_{z \to i} (z-i)\frac{(z-i)}{(z^2+1)^3} $ 
I used two times L'Hospital's rule on this formula, but I still cant get the result. Where is my mistake and how do I determine holomorphic range?

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is valid for poles of order 1, note that you have 
$$
f(z)=\frac{z-i}{(z^2+1)^3}=\frac{1}{(z+i)^3(z-i)^2}
$$
and thus you have poles of order 2 and 3. I'll let you take it from here.

Comment: Here is what I tried for residue near $i$: $Res(f,i)=\lim_{z \to i} \frac{d}{dz}(z-i)\frac{(1)}{(z+i)^3(z-i)^2} =\lim_{z \to i} \frac{(-5z+i)}{(z-i)^3(z+i)^4}$ And when I try to use  L'Hospital's rule here,I will again have term $(z-i)$ in denominator?

Comment: for a pole of order $n$ at $a$ you multiply by $(z-a)^n$. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)

Comment: Great, I finally did it. Can you just help me with type of singularity ofr $-i$? For $i$ I think it is pole, cause $\lim_{z \to z_0} f(z)=\infty  $. But I have trouble with calculating limit for $-i$.

Comment: It is absolutely a pole, but what you said holds for essential singularities as well. Make sure you know the difference. The computation is nearly identical for $-i$